# Validation of model and properties when current values are invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

What would be the best way to implement a validation in ASP.NET MVC 3 when it is to be triggered ***only*** if the user changed the value. It should not trigger if the current value is invalid but user did not change it. For example

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(10, 20)]
    public int? SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public int? AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If the user inputs value outside of range 10 and 20, the default ASP.NET MVC validations trigger both on server and client (unobtrusive). However, if the current value of SomeProperty is invalid (say 25) but user only changes the value of AnotherProperty, the validation for SomeProperty still gets triggered both on server and client. How would we implement a validation that allows existing invalid value for a given property only if it is not changed by the user. So in this case if SomeProperty has a value of 25 (which is invalid) and the user only changes the value of AnotherProperty, the validation should not trigger. If user changes the value of SomeProperty to anything other than 25 (current value), it should be validated and invalid values should not be allowed.

Comment: such behavior is not available out of the box. you have to code it yourself. perhaps by inheriting from ValidationAttribute

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, may be using custom validation. I was wondering if someone has some idea or has seen something like this. It is needed where the legacy DB has invalid data but going forward the validations are to be performed on things that are modified.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is the validation attribute that might get you there.

```
public class RangeIfNotEqualToAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        string otherProperty;
        public RangeIfNotEqualToAttribute(string otherProperty, int rangeStart, int rangeEnd) :base(rangeStart,rangeEnd)
        {
            this.otherProperty = otherProperty;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.GetType().GetProperty(otherProperty);
            var oldValue = (int)otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (oldValue == (int)value)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }
    }
```

it inherits from RangeAttribute and returns `base.IsValid` if current value is not equal to the older one (it assumes that you are carrying the old value in some other property of the same model. so to use it you have to make following changes in your model

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public int BackupProperty{get;set;}
    [Required]
    [RangeIfNotEqualTo("BackupProperty",10, 20)]
    public int? SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public int? AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

when passing model to view you have to copy value of `SomeProperty` into `BackupProperty` as well. Furthermore, you have to render a hidden field for `BackupProperty` so it gets posted back with the model. Hidden field is also important if you want to implement `IClientValidatable` to enable client side validation. you can see at [this post](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for implementation of `IClientValidatable` in similar scenario